# Vimscript syntax with use of registry

Tags: vim, syntax

I am trying to copy in Vim that does not have clipboard support (xclip will be used, do not suggest to enable clipboard support somehow, please).

I am just, lost with the syntax, adding in and expanding variables, then handling escaping characters, I have to find a better way to do this.

```
" ctrl-c to copy to clipboard
vnoremap <C-c> "cy :call system('echo -n "' . escape(@c, '"') . '" > ' . tmp . ' ; xclip ' . shellescape(tmp) . ' -selection clipboard ; rm -rf ' . tmp . ' & disown')<CR><CR>
```

All of this works, don't worry about the tmp variable, just the 'c' registry is not being expanded literally, instead, it will run into issues when the copied content had '\' characters.

also tried substituting, but it created more issues than it solves, using shellescape also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding and troubleshooting Vim mappings can be quite intricate, especially when dealing with shell commands and escaping issues. Let's break down your current mapping and address the problem with the 'c' register and escaping characters.

Your current mapping is:

```
vnoremap <C-c> "cy :call system('echo -n "' . escape(@c, '"') . '" > ' . tmp . ' ; xclip ' . shellescape(tmp) . ' -selection clipboard ; rm -rf ' . tmp . ' & disown')<CR><CR>
```

This mapping does the following:

1. `"cy`: Yanks the visually selected text into the 'c' register.
2. `:call system(...)`: Executes a shell command.
3. The shell command constructs an echo command to output the contents of the 'c' register, pipes it to xclip to copy it to the clipboard, and then cleans up a temporary file.

The issue seems to be with how the contents of the 'c' register are being handled, especially with backslashes (`\`). Let's try to refine the approach:

1. Escaping Backslashes: When dealing with backslashes in Vim script, they often need to be escaped. This is because backslashes are used as escape characters in many programming contexts, including shell commands. You might need to replace each `\` with `\\`.
2. Use of `shellescape()`: This function is designed to escape a string for safe use as a shell command argument. However, it might not handle backslashes as you expect, depending on the context.

Here's a revised approach to try:

```
vnoremap <C-c> "cy :let @c = substitute(@c, '\\', '\\\\', 'g') | call system('echo -n "' . @c . '" | xclip -selection clipboard')<CR>
```

This mapping does the following:

`"cy`: Yanks the visually selected text into the 'c' register.
`:let @c = substitute(@c, '\\', '\\\\', 'g')`: Replaces each backslash in the 'c' register with two backslashes.
`call system(...)`: Executes the echo command to output the contents of the 'c' register to xclip.

This approach should handle backslashes more reliably. However, be aware that dealing with shell commands and Vim's escaping can be tricky, and this solution might need further refinement based on your specific use case and environment.

Comment: I literally said I tried substituting